# Has the Helmholtz decomposition of the $\mathbf{E}$ field from the Liénard–Wiechert potentials been worked out?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields, lienard-wiechert

If you look at Maxwell's equations for $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t)$ they split neatly into two categories. They are:
\begin{align}
   \nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t)&=\frac{\rho(\mathbf{x},t)}{\epsilon_0},\ \mathrm{and} & \nabla\times\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t) & = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial t}.
\end{align}
Examined in light of [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition), these equations could be read as: electric charge produces irrotational electric fields, and changing magnetic fields produce solenoidal electric fields.

The electric field from the [Liénard–Wiechert potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential) is given by equation 14.14 from [Jackson's "Classical Electrodynamics" (3rd Ed)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Classical+Electrodynamics%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471309321) as
$$\mathbf{E}_{LW}(\mathbf{x},t) = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{\mathbf{n}-\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\gamma^2(1 - \boldsymbol{\beta}\cdot\mathbf{n})^3 R^2} \right]_{\mathrm{ret}} + \frac{q}{4\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}}\left[\frac{\mathbf{n}\times\left[(\mathbf{n}-\boldsymbol{\beta})\times \dot{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right]}{(1 - \boldsymbol{\beta}\cdot\mathbf{n})^3 R}\right]_{\mathrm{ret}},$$
where Jackson's emphasis is on the separation of radiation fields (second term) from the near field (first term).

Has someone already done the Helmholtz decomposition of $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{LW}}(\mathbf{x},t)$, and if so, what is it?

Equally useful for my purposes would be the Helmholtz decomposition of [Jefimenko's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations) for the electric field:
\begin{align}
   \mathbf{E}_J(\mathbf{x},t) &= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \left[\left(\frac{\rho(\mathbf{x}',t_r)}{\left|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'\right|^3} + \frac{1}{c\left|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'\right|^2} \frac{\partial \rho(\mathbf{x}',t_r)}{\partial t}\right)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}') - \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|c^2} \frac{\partial\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x}',t_r)}{\partial t}\right]\operatorname{d}^3x' \\
    t_r&\equiv t-\frac{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|}{c}.
\end{align}

A big part of the reason for being interested in the HD of $\mathbf{E}$ using either of the above formulae for it is because the separation is trivial in the [Coulomb gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#Coulomb_gauge) because when $\mathbf{A}$ is solenoidal it doesn't contribute to the irrotational part of $\mathbf{E}$. Thus
\begin{align}
   \mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{irrot}}(\mathbf{x},t) & = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'}{|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|^3} \rho(\mathbf{x}',t)\operatorname{d}^3x', \ \mathrm{and} \\
   \mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{sol}}(\mathbf{x},t) & = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \nabla \times \int \left[\int_0^{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|/c} t' \frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'}{\left|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'\right|^3} \times \dot{\mathbf{J}}(\mathbf{x}',t-t') \operatorname{d}t'\right] \operatorname{d}^3x',
\end{align}
and I cannot see what property of $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{sol}}(\mathbf{x},t)$ allows it to cancel the apparent instantaneous nature of $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{irrot}}(\mathbf{x},t)$.

Comment: May be I'am wrong but I think that the HD-problem of $\:\mathbf{E}_{_{\rm LW}}\:$ is equivalent (must be restricted) to the HD-problem of $\:\mathbf{A}_{_{\rm LW}}$, the last being the Liénard–Wiechert vector potential, since if
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}_{_{\rm LW}}=\boldsymbol{-}\boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi+\boldsymbol{\nabla}\boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\Psi}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}

Comment: then
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}_{_{\rm LW}}=\boldsymbol{-}\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi_{_{\rm LW}}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{A}_{_{\rm LW}}}{\partial t}=\boldsymbol{-}\boldsymbol{\nabla}\left(\phi_{_{\rm LW}}-\dfrac{\partial  \psi}{\partial t}\right)\boldsymbol{+}\boldsymbol{\nabla}\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{\Psi}}{\partial t}\right)
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
....

Comment: May be I'am wrong but I think that the HD-problem of $\:\mathbf{E}_{_{\rm LW}}\:$ could be solved if we could solve the HD-problem of $\:\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{A}_{_{\rm LW}}}{\partial t}\:$ or $\:\mathbf{A}_{_{\rm LW}}\:$  the last being the Liénard–Wiechert vector potential (possibly the two problems are not equivalent, as I think in a previous comment of mine).